# Error while trying to add 'application_readable: true' to app.yaml file

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app.yaml

I've been trying to add this `application_readable: true` to app.yaml file and i get this error!

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 103, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 381, in <module>
    main()
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 369, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 105, in start
    env_variables=parsed_env_variables)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 864, in __init__
    env_variables)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 131, in __init__
    self._config_path)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 454, in _parse_configuration
    config, files = appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 82, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py", line 2482, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 227, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 178, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unexpected attribute "application_readable" for mapping type script.
  in "app.yaml", line 10, column
```

and my app.yaml file is like this

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  application_readable: true
```

where is the problem?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `application_readable` flag only makes sense for `static_files` and/or `static_dir` type handlers. That's because that static content is by default stored in a different place than the application code. From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element):

> **application_readable**
>
> Optional. Boolean. By default, files declared in static file
>   handlers are uploaded as static data and are only served to end users.
>   They cannot be read by an application. If this field is set to true,
>   the files are also uploaded as code data so your application can read
>   them. Both uploads are charged against your code and static data
>   storage [resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Code).

Scripts for non-static handlers are already part of the application, adding the flag doesn't make a lot of sense. Of course, one could argue that this could be done more friendly than this :)

So just don't add that flag for a non-static handler and you should be fine.